# validating model in silverlight MVVM

Tags: c#, validation, silverlight-4.0, inotifydataerrorinfo

how to validate in model in silverlight? 
The code sample what Im trying to achieve  is shown below..

```
 <Grid x:Name="AddnewGrid" Margin="2" DataContext="{Binding SaveUpdateEmp, Mode=TwoWay">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="125"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="EmployeeCode" Text="EmployeeCode" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="EmployeeCodeSprtr" Text=":" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtEmployeeCode" Text="{Binding EmployeeCode, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBox>

        <TextBlock x:Name="EmployeeName" Text="Employee Name" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="EmployeeNameSprtr" Text=":" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtEmployeeName" Text="{Binding EmployeeName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBox>

        <TextBlock x:Name="EmployeePW" Text="PassWord" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="EmployeePWSprtr" Text=":" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtEmployeePW" Text="{Binding EmployeePW, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBox>

        <TextBlock x:Name="EmployeeDesg" Text="Designation" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="EmployeeDesgSprtr" Text=":" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtEmployeeDesg" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding EmployeeDesg, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBox>

        <TextBlock x:Name="DepartmentId" Text="DepartmentID" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="DepartmentIdSprtr" Text=":" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtDepartmentId" Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding DepartmentId, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBox>

        <TextBlock x:Name="DepartmentName" Text="Department" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="DepartmentNameSprtr" Text=":" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtDepartmentName" Grid.Row="5" Text="{Binding DepartmentName, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBox>

        <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" Click="CancelButton_Click" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2"  Width="75" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <Button x:Name="OKButton" Content="Save" Click="OKButton_Click" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Width="75" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    </Grid>
```

Here the SaveUpdateEmp is object of propertyclass in model. How to validate these fields.??

Comment: <TextBox x:Name="IdTextBox" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"  
      Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" MaxLength="5" 
      Text="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True,
      NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>

Comment: But the Id is coming from wcf service. Then how can i throw validation
exception for Textbox..??

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` on your model and make sure that you have `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True` on the controls/properties that you need to validate.  I can give you a code sample, but I think this does a better job than I can - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.95).aspx.  If you have questions, I'm happy to answer.

Comment: But I am getting model object using wcf service, then how to throw exception throw servies.?? If possible can you please provide some code snippet..??

Comment: If you're getting your data from a service you'll have to create a second model and map the one from the service to the one you created. The one you create implements INotifyDataErrorInfo.  I think a better way is to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo in your view-model, make this your view's datacontext, and map have the view-model set the values in your model.  I can give you a sample if you need it.

Comment: @siva...Please disregard my last comment.  I was thinking of something else.  My apologies.  I'll get you an appropriate code sample soon.

Comment: @siva...I can't give you a better example than the MSFT link I provided.  I think the key is for you to map the service model to your app's model.